# how to get stop working of cell value changed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my C# application I am using one `datagridview`, in these grid I am using one event of grid that is cell value changed, I used some calculations in the cell value change, now the problem is very slow while entering data's on grid.

how can I solve these .?

Here I am showing my grid cell value change event code:

```
private void dgvSalesInvoice_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsSetGridValueChange == true)
        {

            BatchSP spBatch = new BatchSP();
            UnitConvertionSP spUnitConversion = new UnitConvertionSP();
            DataTable dtblUnitConversion = new DataTable();
            decimal decBatchId = 0;
            string strBarcode = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1)
                {
                    if (dgvSalesInvoice.RowCount > 1)
                    {



                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "dgvtxtSalesInvoicembUnitName")
                        {
                            if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoicembUnitName"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoicembUnitName"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                            {
                                UnitConvertionSP SpUnitConvertion = new UnitConvertionSP();
                                DataTable dtblUnitByProduct = new DataTable();
                                dtblUnitByProduct = SpUnitConvertion.UnitConversionIdAndConRateViewallByProductId(dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceProductId"].Value.ToString());
                                foreach (DataRow drUnitByProduct in dtblUnitByProduct.Rows)
                                {
                                    if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoicembUnitName"].Value.ToString() == drUnitByProduct.ItemArray[0].ToString())
                                    {
                                        dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceUnitConversionId"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(drUnitByProduct.ItemArray[2].ToString());
                                        dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceConversionRate"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(drUnitByProduct.ItemArray[3].ToString());
                                        decimal decNewConversionRate = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceConversionRate"].Value.ToString());
                                        decimal decNewRate = (decCurrentRate * decCurrentConversionRate) / decNewConversionRate;
                                        dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceRate"].Value = Math.Round(decNewRate, PublicVariables._inNoOfDecimalPlaces);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                             if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceDiscountPercentage"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceDiscountPercentage"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty || dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceDiscountAmount"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceDiscountAmount"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                        {
                            discountCalculation("", e.RowIndex);
                            if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].OwningColumn.Name == "dgvtxtSalesInvoiceDiscountPercentage")
                            {

                                if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceTaxName"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceGrossValue"].Value != null)
                                {
                                    taxAmountCalculation(e.RowIndex);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].OwningColumn.Name == "dgvcmbSalesInvoiceTaxName")
                        {

                            if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceTaxName"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceNetAmount"].Value != null)
                            {
                                if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceTaxName"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceNetAmount"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    {
                                        taxAmountCalculation(e.RowIndex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty || dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceProductName"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceProductName"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                        {
                            discountCalculation("", e.RowIndex);
                        }
                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].OwningColumn.Name == "dgvtxtSalesInvoiceRate")
                        {

                            if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceRate"].Value != null)
                            {
                                if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceRate"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    {
                                        TotalAmountCalculation(e.RowIndex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }


                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceRate"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceRate"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty || dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceProductName"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceProductName"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                        {
                            discountCalculation("", e.RowIndex);
                        }
                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].OwningColumn.Name == "dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty")
                        {

                            if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceRate"].Value != null)
                            {
                                if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceRate"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    {
                                        TotalAmountCalculation(e.RowIndex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }


                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceGrossValue"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceGrossValue"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty || dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceQty"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                        {
                            discountCalculation("", e.RowIndex);
                        }
                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].OwningColumn.Name == "dgvtxtSalesInvoiceGrossValue")
                        {

                            if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceTaxName"].Value != null && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceGrossValue"].Value != null)
                            {
                                if (dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceTaxName"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty && dgvSalesInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceGrossValue"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    {
                                        taxAmountCalculation(e.RowIndex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    if (e.ColumnIndex == dgvSalesInvoice.Columns["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceBatch"].Index)
                    {

                        if (dgvSalesInvoice.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceBatch"].Value != null)
                        {
                            if (dgvSalesInvoice.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceBatch"].Value.ToString() != string.Empty && dgvSalesInvoice.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceBatch"].Value.ToString() != "0")
                            {
                                decBatchId = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesInvoice.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvcmbSalesInvoiceBatch"].Value.ToString());
                                strBarcode = spBatch.ProductBatchBarcodeViewByBatchId(decBatchId);
                                dgvSalesInvoice.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceBarcode"].Value = strBarcode;
                                if (dgvSalesInvoice.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceProductId"].Value != null)      // here get product rate for sales(standard rate)
                                {
                                    getProductRate(e.RowIndex, Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesInvoice.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvtxtSalesInvoiceProductId"].Value.ToString()), decBatchId);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                CheckInvalidEntries(e);
                SiGridTotalAmountCalculation();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SI: 102" + ex.Message, "OpenMiracle", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I deleted my answer (which I guess that you read and helped you to fix your problem) because of not liking your attitude.